# Docking controls in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, docking

I have 10 controls inside my form i want to dock them efficiently inside my form. i need a free library for doing this (except Dotnetmagic). can anyone suggest me a good library.

Regards,
karthikeyan saravanan

Answer (score 5):

Weifen-Luo's Docking Library is very well. We use it in our company:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/dockpanelsuite/. You can have Visual-Studio-like docking environment, with this library.